# Thread was being aborted Error ? In asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am using code, to download the documnet which is uploaded, which is written in item command event of datalist, but it s giving error like "Thread was being aborted" can you help me to solve this, thank you. My code is as fallows.

```
protected void dtlstMagazine_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
   try 
   { 
    objItMagBe.TitleId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    dts = new DataSet();
    dts = objItMagBL.GetMagzineByTitleID(objItMagBe);
    GetPopularMagazine();

    string Myfile = "../xxxx/DataFiles/" + dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Files"].ToString();
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(Myfile)) == true)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Myfile);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(Myfile));
        Response.End();
        Response.Flush();
    }
   }
   catch
   {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Response.End() is most likely what is causing that. It is because it is telling ASP.NET that the request is over.

What is the stack trace from the Exception, where does .NET think the exception is being thrown from?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the file is big so the IIS is killing the thread, you should change this in the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime 
    maxRequestLength="1048576"
    executionTimeout="3600"
  />
```

maxRequestLength is in bytes

executionTimeout is in seconds

Answer (score 0):

You sure that doesn't happen in other code not shown ? usually you get that with when you redirect while inside a try-catch

Comment: ya try catch is there, but i not place that here Mr. John

Comment: possibly it is the Response.End() as suggested by Colin , try removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're calling `Response.End()` before `Response.Flush()`. Swap the order of those statements and the issue will go away.