# Getting Thread was being aborted in asp

Tags: asp.net

I'm triying to create a very big text file in an ASP page but I'm getting thread was being aborted exception and I'm not using Response.Redirect/Server.
Do you know why I'm getting this? Or if you can tell me another way to create big text files in ASP?

Something that calls my attention is that this exception not always happens, I run it the first time an it works but the 3 or 4 times next I run it the exception happens and then it works again.

```
GetTextFileName(Byval filename as String) as Boolean
    If Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("./Report/E005/Texts")) Then
        Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath("./Report/E005/Texts"), True)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("./Report/E005/Texts"))
    Else
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("./Report/E005/Texts"))
    End If
    While continue
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("p_minus", minus))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("p_max", max))
        p = New OracleParameter("p_report", OracleType.Cursor)
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
        dt = ejecutar.consulta(cmd, "Report").Tables(0)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            'Writes File
            Dim x As String = Me.GenerateTXT(dt, FolderRoute, fileName & fileCounter.ToString & ".txt", minus)
            dt = Nothing
        ElseIf minus <= 1 Then
            'There was not data
            MsgBox1.ShowMessage("There was not data")
            continue = False
        Else
            'There was not data but I'm not in first page, so I finished data
            continue = False
        End If
        minus += 100000
        max += 100000
        FileCounter += 1
    End While
    'Generate ZIP
    If File.Exists(Server.MapPath(ZipFolder) & ZipName & ".zip") Then
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(ZipFolder) & ZipName & ".zip")
    End If
    zip.AddDirectory(Server.MapPath(RouteFolder))
    zip.Save(Server.MapPath(ZipFolder) & ZipName & ".zip")
    filename = Server.MapPath(ZipFolder) & ZipName & ".zip"
    Return True
 End Function
```

Comment: Someone may be able to help, but we need more details/code to know what's going on. Also, what constitutes a "big" text file?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631182/thread-was-being-aborted-error-in-asp-net

Comment: I'm trying to write the result of a query in the text file, the query brings like 600000 rows

Comment: I add some of the code I use too

Comment: After how long time do you get the thread aborted exception? Usually there are limits in IIS on how long a request is allowed to process before IIS kills it and restarts the process (and you would get a thread aborted exception). Also make sure you're not running out of memory, IIS also monitors memory utilization and kills your process if it consumes too much. In general a web request is probably not the best place for batch processing like this.

Comment: it depends, sometimes the process creates 3 files and then the exception, sometimes just creates one (always working with the same data) and these are the values of the httpRuntime: maxRequestLength="2097151" requestLengthDiskThreshold="20480" executionTimeout="14400"

Comment: You can't use the MessageBox class in ASP.NET. That's for Windows Forms. It will only show up on the server.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a custom control made in Ajax and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I continued debugging and I found out that the part where I delete and create the folders was the part that was firing out the exception. I think so because I comented that part and the exception did not fire again. 
But I don't know why was that the problem...