# Exception is calling web service method

Tags: c#, web-services

I am calling a web service method, which is expected to return a data set which has 1 data table with 15K rows. I am getting the following exception in PROD environment, works fine on local.

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 3929948).        
 Exception In Calling GetProductSearch -- System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Data.DataTextReader.Read()
   at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadColumn(DataColumn column, Object[] foundColumns)
   at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadTable(DataTable table, Boolean isNested)
   at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadData(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXmlDiffgram(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, XmlReadMode mode, Boolean denyResolving)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXmlSerializable(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.DataSet.System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, Boolean wrappedAny)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read147_GetProductSearchResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer273.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
```

Comment: may  be it's administartor privelege issue

Comment: perhaps post the code making the call?

Comment: Your response length was too long to send over network probably

Comment: possible duplicate, anyway do the same way - IIS seems to be killing the thread due to large size of data - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631182/thread-was-being-aborted-error-in-asp-net#9631244